# what is the meaning of "unicode = unicode"?

Tags: python

Going over [pyxml module](https://github.com/Alidron/demo-nao/blob/master/alidron-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_xmlgen.py)...

What is the meaning of this assignment?

```
if sys.version_info >= (3,0):
    def u(s):
        return s
    def unicode(x, errors=None):
        if hasattr(x, '__unicode__'):
            return x.__unicode__()
        return str(x)
else:
    def u(s):
        return unicode(s)
    unicode = unicode  #  <<<<<< This one >>>>>>>>
```

Comment: It binds the builtin name `unicode` to a module-global name (which is also `unicode`). This mimics how `def unicode` creates a module-global name. Either branch then allows fetching `module.unicode`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so, for Py3+, `from module import unicode` would have imported the method defined here, and for Py2, it would import the variable `unicode` that is the global `unicode`, basically doing nothing except for not breaking the `from module import unicode` line?

Comment: Yes, there should be no other observable side-effect. It also makes name lookup for `unicode` faster (builtins are checked after globals) on both CPython (150 ns -> 124 ns) and PyPy (8.67 ns -> 0.65 ns), though this is usually not significant in total.

Comment: Intersting. So for a module that is called a lot, assigning an imported module name to its name (e.g. `math=math`) could improve performence. cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It binds the builtin name `unicode` to a module-global name (which is also named `unicode`). This mimics how `def unicode` creates a module-global name. As a result, either branch then allows fetching the name.

```
from module import unicode  # unicode is defined in all cases
```

Since the module globals are always checked before the `builtins` module, it also speeds up lookup of the `unicode` name. For an often-used builtin name, this can improve overall performance.

```
$ python3 -m perf timeit 'str("hello world")'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 150 ns +- 12 ns
$ python3 -m perf timeit -s 'import builtins' -s 'str = builtins.str' 'str("hello world")'
.....................
Mean +- std dev: 124 ns +- 3 ns

$ pypy3 -m perf timeit 'str("hello world")'
.........
Mean +- std dev: 8.28 ns +- 0.39 ns
$ pypy3 -m perf timeit -s 'import builtins' -s 'str = builtins.str' 'str("hello world")'
........
Mean +- std dev: 0.65 ns +- 0.01 ns
```